# How do I get user record in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I can fetch the userRecordID, but I get an error whenever I try to fetch the record associated with that ID. Any suggestions? Code and error below:

```
myContainer.fetchUserRecordID { (thisID, thisError) in
            if let userError = thisError {
                print("DEBUG: error getting user id; \(userError)")
            } else {
                if let userID = thisID {
                    self.publicDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: userID, completionHandler: { (fetchedUser, fetchedError) in
                        if let thisError = fetchedError {
                            print("DEBUG: error getting user record; \(thisError)")
                        }
```

`DEBUG: error getting user record; <CKError 0x174045010: "Internal Error" (1/5001); "Couldn't get a PCS object to unwrap encrypted data for field encryptedPublicSharingKey: (null)">`

Error in the code, or my fault for trying beta software (iOS 10, Swift 3 & xCode-beta 8.0 beta 2 (8S162m)

Answer (score -1):

From your example it is not clear if `self.publicDatabase` is equal to `myContainer.publicCloudDatabase`.

Make sure you fetch it from the same container's database, otherwise it will obviously not work.

```
myContainer.fetchUserRecordID { userID, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("DEBUG: error getting user id; \(userError)")
        return
    }
    guard let userRecID = userID else {
        print("DEBUG: Can't unwrap userID")
        return
    }
    myContainer.publicCloudDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: userRecID, completionHandler: { (fetchedUser, fetchedError) in
        //handle the error and the user
        print("DEBUG: User fetch FINISHED!", fetchedUser)
    })
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I needed to change from publicDatabase to privateDatabase.

`self.publicDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: userID, completionHandler: { (fetchedUser, fetchedError) in`

to

`self.privateDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: userID, completionHandler: { (fetchedUser, fetchedError) in`

Comment: I'm getting this error with publicDatabase, but I need to be getting it from the publicDatabase.